# Postgresql: Select from first table or replace with data from second table

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am new to postgresql and want to know what is the most effective way to select data from one table, and if there is a row with same id in sedond table, then select data from this second table and not the first one.

Ex.: I have 2 tables with same structure eg. `products` and `products_new` with columns `id, title, price`.
I want to display all rows from `products`, but if there is a row with same `id` in table `products_new`, i want to display values for this `id` from `products_new` table

```
table products:
'ab', 'Title AB', 100
'cd', 'Title CD', 200
'ef', 'Title EF', 300
'gh', 'Title GH', 400

table products_new:
'ab', 'New Title', 100
'gh', 'Title GH', 800

result:
'ab', 'New Title', 100
'cd', 'Title CD', 200
'ef', 'Title EF', 300
'gh', 'Title GH', 800
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    id,
    coalesce(pn.title, p.title) as title,
    coalesce(pn.price, p.price) as price
from
    products p
    left join
    products_new pn using(id)
```

The `left join` will preserve all rows from the left table even if there is no correspondence in the right table. Coalesce will get the first not null value.